# How to include a picture in HTML from another drive?

Tags: javascript, html, css, path, frontend

I am learning HTML, CSS and javascript in preparation for my school project involving frontend development. Here's the question.

> When I was trying to insert a picture in one of my HTML file. The picture is located in drive C: and the HTML file is located in drive E:.I used a `<image>` tag.

practice.html: `E:\Frontend-Notes\Mainpage\practice.html`
10-11.jpg: `C:\Users\wangz\Pictures\WallPaper\Scenery\10-11.jpg`

```
   <image src = "C:\Users\wangz\Pictures\WallPaper\Scenery\10-11.jpg">
```

Then I ctrl+click-ed the path which is supposed to be an absolute path, VS code showed an error message below.
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DuWK9.png)

I don't know how to deal with it.

Comment: Please copy the image to E:\Frontend-Notes\Mainpage folder

Comment: Or <img src="file:///C:\Users\wangz\Pictures\WallPaper\Scenery\10-11.jpg"> put file:/// before path

Comment: if you code a website you need to make it run independly on a webserver not your lcoal machine. So in th end you should make a folder for your entire website files including all the images so it would actually run on a webserver.

Answer (score 0):

So, you can solve your problem by two ways--
1.) Cut and paste your 10-11.jpg file in your project folder, i.e.,
`E:\Frontend-Notes\Mainpage`

2.) You need to put the address in src as given below --
`file:///C:\Users\wangz\Pictures\WallPaper\Scenery\10-11.jpg`

Maybe it helps you.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try it out later.

Answer (score 0):

A quick fix is to move the image you want to use to the same directory with your project, or within your project directory create a folder for the images you'll be using. This is not only a good practice but also a more suitable way to keep your project files organised.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your answer is really helpful.